# Restaurant sending orders every 5 minutes on average

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

Restaurant sending orders every 5 minutes on average, What's the probability in a particular day, that after the second order, an hour will pass until the next order sending.

I can conclude that's it's about Exponential distribution with $\lambda = 12$, because our time unit is hours, and we have 12 orders in one hour.

I'm not sure how to refer to the meaning of 'after the second order'.

What I've written so far is $Pr[X \ge 1] = 1 - Pr[X \le 1] = 1 - e^{-\lambda  t}$ and $t = 1$

Comment: I think the **only** thing wrong with your main equation is that $Pr[X \ge 1] = 1 - Pr[X \le 1] = 1 - e^{-\lambda  t}$ should have been $Pr[X \ge 1] = 1 - Pr[X \le 1] = 1 - [1-  e^{-\lambda  t}] = e^{-12}.$

Comment: @BruceET Oh wow, I haven't noticed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea to compute $P(X > 1)$ where $W \sim \mathsf{Exp}(\lambda = 12)$
is OK, but you have made a simple mistake in writing the equation. Please
look at it carefully. Your equation will give an answer $\approx 1.$

Intuitively, the probability of waiting more than an hour for the next order
must be quite small--because you have already figured out that on average there
are 12 orders an hour (one every five minutes).

You have correctly adjusted $\lambda$ and correctly applied the 'no-memory property' to look only one hour ahead (ignoring the past). So you pretty much understand what's
going on. I'll let you find your simple mistake on your own. That way maybe you won't make it again on an exam or in an important application.

In R statistical software `pexp` is an exponential CDF with the rate
specified by the second argument. So the computation below gives the answer.
However, this is just for reinforcement; you can easily compute the result
on a simple calculator.

```
1 - pexp(1, 12)
## 6.144212e-06
```

Also, sometimes a simple sketch of the PDF helps avoid simple errors.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand $12$. If the average of an exponential distribution is $5$ then the parameter is $\frac15$. $12$ is the parameter of a Poisson process...

Comment: Different parameterization I think: _Mean_ parameter is $\mu = 1/12$ hours or five minutes.. _Rate_ parameter is $\lambda = 12$ per hour. R (an apparently OP's book) uses rate.

Comment: Another way to look at it: Prob of no order in next min is $e^{-1/5} = 0.8187308,$ Prob of no order in next hour is $0.8187308^{60} =$ `6.144212e-06`.

Comment: I give up because I don't understand... (Not understanding equals having to give up)

Comment: @zoli. At least you made me think about it **really** hard. Thanks for that.

Comment: The same : ) :)

Comment: Thanks Bruce. Appreciated.

Comment: How would you write the probability without using the "no-memory property"? $Pr[ X > x_0 + x_1| X > x_0]$. what would be $x_0,x_1$ in this case?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626522/twelve-orders-being-sent-in-an-hour Can you take a look @BruceET