# twelve orders being sent in an hour

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

Restaurant is sending orders every 5 minutes on average.

**Question:** From 15:00 until 15:05, two orders were ordered. What's the probability that the next order will be ordered until 15:10 ?

I can conclude that's it's about Exponential distribution with $\lambda = 12$, because our time unit is hours, and we have 12 orders in one hour.

I'm not sure how to refer to "From 15:00 until 15:05, two orders were ordered".

But without that info. I can tell that the probability that the next order will be ordered is less than 5 minutes, thus $Pr[X \le 1/12]$.

Comment: You need more information on the orders for that. Do they depend on each other or do all orders arrive independently of each other with a given chance?

Comment: The question "What's the probability that the next order will be ordered until 15:10 ?" is not clear.  It probably should say "What's the probability that the next order will not be ordered until after15:10 ?" or "What's the probability that the next order will be ordered by 15:10 ?"  The assumption of an exponential distribution is reasonable but not specified in the problem, either.  Maybe the orders come in exactly every $5$ minutes on the $5$ minutes.

Comment: If the distribution is exponential, it is memoryless so the information about what happened between $1500$ and $1505$ does not matter at all.

Comment: @RossMillikan That's exactly what I thought too. Can you explain please why it's memoryless?

Comment: That is the defining property of an exponential distribution.  The chance of something happening in each block of time is independent of when it is or previous history.  It only depends on the length of the interval.

Comment: @RossMillikan That makes sense now. Thanks Ross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the exponential distribution has the property of "memorylessness". This means previous orders do not increase or decrease the probability of new 
orders.

What is the probability that someone orders in the next five minutes?

That is indeed Exp(12,1/12) (Exponential distribution with $\lambda = 12$ and time 1/12 = 5 minutes). Hope this helps